# NetXtreme II (BCM 5708) UDP Packets Per Second?

Tags: networking, sockets

Does anyone else have any benchmarks on how many packets per second this NIC can receive without dropping any UDP traffic? Using 64 byte UDP packets, I'm seeing roughly 100k packets/sec until drops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done testing using multiple `dnsperf` as packet generators and dummy echo programs on an HP DL785 with four such NICs in it running CentOS 5.2

The 100 kpps figure you're seeing is *around* about the right order of magnitude - in my experience beyond that the kernel keeps one core fully occupied just handling the interrupts from the NIC.